# If com 3 condições e ao menos 2 verdadeiras?

Tags: jquery, if, condição

Suponhamos que eu tenha o seguinte `if`

```
if(a || b || c == true)
```

Neste caso, basta que apenas um dos valores seja verdadeiro para ativar a condição, porém eu gostaria que a condição se ativasse somente quando ao menos 2 dos valores passados sejam verdadeiros, é possível? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 5):

Gambiarra baseada em *type juggling*:

```
if(a + b + c >= 2) {

}
```

Explicação: com o operador de adição, os valores booleanos serão convertidos em números, com `true` valendo `1` e `false` valendo `0`. Se o resultado da soma for 2 ou mais, quer dizer que tem pelo menos 2 `true`. Isso funciona contanto que as suas variáveis sejam do tipo Boolean, ou do tipo Number com valores `0` ou `1`. Caso necessário, faça a conversão delas antes do `if`.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se existe uma forma "*automática*" de controlar isso, mas você pode *agrupar* as condições:

```
if ((a && b) || (a && c) || (b && c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar duas condições, você deve utilizar o && ao invés do ||

|| significa  OU

&& significa E

if (a && b || c)

---

Se A E B for verdadeiro OU C

Ou seja, C se for verdadeiro, já era. Passou.

Comment: Se entendi bem, a pergunta exige que duas das condições sejam verdadeiras; nesta resposta, se `A` e `B` forem falsas e `C` verdadeira, ele entra no `if`. Ou entendi errado? :P

Comment: Se A e B forem verdadeiras ao mesmo tempo, OU o C for verdadeiro, entra no IF.
Ou seja, se O A for verdadeiro, B false e C verdadeiro, vai entrar pela regra do C.
Se A e B forem verdadeiros, entra na primeira regra.